# SeleniumHQ Automated DB Populate

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've been on the quest for the past week, to find out how to automate some way, to fetch ID's, classes and so on, from HTML source code of a page.
My objective is to create a database, from where my java program will get data, to create automated tests, depending on the elements found on the page. 
To populate that Database manualy would take me ages, since the website is huge. I would have to inspect all elements by hand, and get the xpath from every single one of them.

So, what i was looking for on the web, is a way to actualy detect all elements present on a page, and then get all the information about them. Therefore, save that information on a database, after it beeing filtered and treated.

Do you guys know any way of doing so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
List<WebElement> childs = body.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
for(WebElement child : childs){
   // Get data for each element
}
```

Comment: Hi there, i've tried the code you gave me, didn't give me the expected results. Here's a line from the hundreds of repeated lines it gave.

[[[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (dcbefd0b7d9807f6db4029680304a064)] -> tag name: body]] -> xpath: .//*]

Maybe i am not using the correct import for java.

I'm using import java.util.List;

Comment: @PMacedo Well show the code you are now using. Edit your original question to show this new code.